# How to express hi/lo byte of a label in crasm

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am trying to move my project from xa (which I found rather buggy) to crasm, which is the other 6502 assembler that comes with debian.

My project contains a lot of lines like

```
ldx #<pname
ldy #>pname
```

where `pname` is a label where a string may be found. How is that done in crasm? I couldn't find any such thing as `<` and `>` in the man page.

Comment: What's your target platform?  Something like 64tasm or cc65 might be a better choice.

Comment: That's an idea. I'm writing for the c64. And you just reminded me that cc65 comes with an assembler.

Comment: I can certainly endorse ca65. It's pretty powerful for a 6502 cross assembler. It also comes with a nice disassembler.

Comment: @JeremyP, when I tried ca65 I got a load of extraneous fluff in my binary, including what looked like symbol tables and other linker's business. Do you know what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: That sounds like its given you an object file that still needs to be linked. Does the result have a `.o` extension?

Answer (score 7):

CRASM is ... well ... let's say frugal - and works more or less along a C-like expression syntax. And as with C, there are no separate operators for low/high byte of an address. So

`>label`  needs to become `(label >> 8)`

while

`<label` is to be changed to `(label & $FF)`

(The last can, AFAIK, be omitted - but keeping it makes it way more readable).

Comment: "lets say frugal" - I *love* understatement :-)

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear that crasm has shorthand for getting the high and low byte of a value.  You'll have to do it explicitly with the `&` and `>>` operators:

High byte:

```
ldx #pname>>8
```

Low byte:

```
ldx #pname&255
```